# Activate tab via external link (list based)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to activate a tab via a link e.g.#blahblah However, to do that, the tabs would have to be link based but they are list based. Can anyone tell me on how i can do it with my current setup? e.g. website.com/#tab2

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content").find("[id^='tab']").hide(); // Hide all content
    $("#tabs li:first").attr("id","current"); // Activate the first tab
    $("#content #tab1").fadeIn(); // Show first tab's content

    $('#tabs a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).closest("li").attr("id") == "current"){ //detection for current tab
         return;       
        }
        else{             
          $("#content").find("[id^='tab']").hide(); // Hide all content
          $("#tabs li").attr("id",""); //Reset id's
          $(this).parent().attr("id","current"); // Activate this
          $('#' + $(this).attr('name')).fadeIn(); // Show content for the current tab
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
 <ul id="tabs">
    <li><a href="#" name="tab1">Description</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="tab5">Reviews</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="content">
    <div id="tab1">
    </div>

    <div id="tab5">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that

```
<a href="#" name="tab1" target="_blank">Discription</a>
```

would work.

Comment: It didnt work - i used the following `<a href="?ObjectPath=/Shops/Products/Product1#" name="tab5" target="_blank">` I am on the category level and from the category level, i need a link that opens up a tab in the product level.